# Regex pattern to match username requirements

Tags: regex

Can someone please provide me with a regex pattern to match these requirements?

- between 3 and 20 characters
- begins with a letter
- cannot end in a period(.)
- can contain: a-z, 0-9, period(.), hyphen(-), underscore(_)

I'm new to regex. I've tried `^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_.-]+$`, given to me by someone, and I started to do my own with `[a-z,A-Z,.]{3,20}[0-9]*`

I will be using this in JavaScript but so far I've just been testing at regexr.com because it is convenient.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Maybe consider a regex tutorial, this isn't too diffcult at all.

Comment: I added what I have tried. It's not much, but regex is confusing and I've always avoided it when I could. Now I can't lol.

Comment: Please also add which language or tool you are using, regex syntax and possibilities can differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/^[a-z][\w.-]{1,18}[\w-]$/i` as a pattern. A little breakdown:

- `^` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start of the string, as we want to check the whole string
- `[a-z]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) matching letters a-z, lowercase and also uppercase due to the `i`-[Modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). This is used for your *begins with a letter* condition
- `[\w.-]{1,18}` is a character class matching letters, numbers, underscore (= `\w`), dot and hyphen. It is repeated one to eighteen times to fit *between 3 and 20 characters* (+ 2 characters at start and end)
- `[\w-]` is basically the same character class, but without the dot, to fit *cannot end in a period(.)*
- `$` is an anchor for the end of the string

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and really is quite simple after reading your explanation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are a lot of useful tutorials and online testers around, it really isn't too difficult to work with regular expressions, no fear ;) Please accept my answer, if it works.